# Can I partition by 3 variables

Tags: mysql, partition

I would like to add a third partition to the table below. 
As an example, how would I add an subpartition "item_of_sale" for each week_of_sale partition? While I can index this third variable, partitioning by this variable should have much better performance.

```
alter table MyTable 
    PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR_of_Sales )
        SUBPARTITION BY HASH(Week_Of_Sales)
        SUBPARTITIONS 52 (
    PARTITION p2012 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
    PARTITION p2013 VALUES LESS THAN (2014),
    PARTITION p2014 VALUES LESS THAN (2015),
    PARTITION p2015 VALUES LESS THAN (2016),
    PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
    PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
    PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (2019)
    PARTITION pmax  VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```